# Is it normal that the same function returns two different results on two differents components?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an react-native app where i receive data from firestore. I put all the data received in on array and i use the lenght to make test before rendering. In the screen A the lenght is more than 0 but in the screen B it's 0 but both arrays contain data.

it tried copy the code from one page to another but nothing, same result from both screens

Screen A

```
getData = async () => {
    const ref = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("PlatPost")
      .where("active", "==", true);
    this.unsubscribe = await ref.onSnapshot(this.parseData);
    await this.setState({ loading: false });
  };

  parseData = async querySnapshot => {
    await querySnapshot.forEach(async doc => {
      let _data = await doc.data();
      let key = await doc.id;
      let normalDate = await this.convertToDate(_data.date.toDate());
      await this.data.push({ ..._data, key, normalDate });
    });
    await this.setState({ data: [...this.data] });
    await console.log(this.data) //Printing the result in console
  };
```

Screen B

```
getData = async () => {
    const ref = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Notification")
      .where("recipient.id", "==", this.state.userId);
    this.unsubscribe = await ref.onSnapshot(this.parseData);
    await this.setState({ loading: false });
  };

  parseData = async querySnapshot => {
    await querySnapshot.forEach(async doc => {
      let _data = await doc.data();
      let key = await doc.id;
      let normalDate = await this.convertToDate(_data.date.toDate());
      await this.data.push({ ..._data, key, normalDate });
    });
    await this.setState({ data: [...this.data] });
    await console.log(this.data) //Priniting the result in console 
  };
```

Result from screen A

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {username: "K", active: true, …}
1: {username: "Cuisinier", active: true, …}
2: {username: "K", active: true, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I expected the same result as the screen A but got this on screen B

```
[]
0: {username: "hermann", active: true, …}
1: {username: "Test", active: true, …}
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```